# Setting text at right side of screen

Tags: css, html, positioning

Below is how my screen look like

```
*********************************************************
*                      Welcome to Mysite                *
*          ______________________________________       *
*                    Welcome user, logout.              *
*               Mon, 02-Jul-2012 22:59:07 AST           *
*          ______________________________________       *
*                                                       *
*                                                       *
*                                                       *
*                                                       *
```

Code I have is

```
<html>
    <body>
        <center>
            Welcome to Mysite<br />
            <hr width="40%" /><br />
            Welcome user, logout</br>
            Mon, 02-Jul-2012 22:59:07 AST<br />
            <hr width="40%" /><br />
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I want is something like below.

```
*********************************************************
*                      Welcome to Mysite                *
*          ______________________________________       *
*                           Welcome user, logout.       *
*                   Mon, 02-Jul-2012 22:59:07 AST       *
*          ______________________________________       *
*                                                       *
*                                                       *
*                                                       *
*                                                       *
```

That means set everything to right. I believe this can be done using CSS, but I don't know how to set the position.

### ***Note*** : Text should not be at the right side of screen. It should be **till** the right side of the horizontal line.

Any idea how to get this done?

---

### Update 1

I don't want output like below.

```
*********************************************************
*                      Welcome to Mysite                *
*          ______________________________________       *
*                                  Welcome user, logout.*
*                          Mon, 02-Jul-2012 22:59:07 AST*
*          ______________________________________       *
*                                                       *
*                                                       *
*                                                       *
*                                                       *
```

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame : You didn't get my problem... I don't want to set at the right side.. I want to set right side of horizontal line that I have..

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame : see Abhisek answer and see the difference. NO NEED FOR DOWNVOTE... This was not normal question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e6sSg/)

You just needed to place the content in a `<div>` and add the following CSS to it.

```css
.container {
    width:40%;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Place it in a `<div>` with proper margins and/or padding and add to the CSS: `text-align: right`

Comment: that is my problem... I don't want to set to the right of the screen. I want it at the end of the horizontal line.. hope you get what I meant to say...

Comment: You should nest those HTML elements